# Include_recipe in chef is not working?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm not sure if it an issue or I'm missing something. 
I'm trying to figure out what is the different between include a recipe and mentioning it in a run list
I have created 3 cookbooks :

1. include_test - includes include_test1
2. include_test1 - includes include_test2
3. include_test2 - has a directory resource

When I try to run ( chef_client ) it while mentioning just "include_test" cookbook in the run_list the directory resource is not picked up

When I try to run it while mentioning "include_test,include_test1" cookbooks it is working as expected.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: No it isn't expected behaviour ... I think.  Try running `chef-client` with logging set to "debug".

Comment: post all three recipes for us and we'll be able to quickly help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no major difference between a recipe being in the run list directly and being invoked by include_recipe. It does affect the value of `node['recipes']` since for stuff in the run list it is statically expanded while include_recipe has to be processed as it happens. The usual issue with include_recipe failing is that you have to make sure to mark the cookbook you are including from as a dependency in your metadata.rb.

Comment: I have it in `metadata.rb`, otherwise it would raise an error when I added it to the run_list .  here you can see some SS - [link](https://github.com/opscode/chef/issues/2303)

Comment: Please put the code up somewhere like gist.github.com so I can take a look.